# Recursively filter items in a multidimensional array do not contain array-type data unless having a whitelisted key

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array, array-filter

I have array the following multidimensional array:

```
$arr = [
    'test' => [
        'access' => 111,
        'aa' => [
            'access' => 222,
            'bb' => 333
        ],
    ],
    'access' => 444,
    'value' => 555
];
```

Desired result:

```
[
  'test' => [
    'access' => 111,
    'aa' => [
      'access' => 222,
    ],
  ],
  'access' => 444,
]
```

My code:

```
function array_filter_recursive($input)
{
    foreach ($input as &$value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $value = array_filter_recursive($value);
        }
    }
    return array_filter($input,function ($key){
            return $key == 'access';
        },ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
}

var_dump(array_filter_recursive($arr));
```

However, my code only returns 1 item.

If I change the function like `return $key != 'access';`, it returns the array without `key == access` but it's not working if `$key == 'access'`.

Comment: The input is the first array, the desired output is the second array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only want to remove a key if it's not named `access` and the value is not a nested array. This way, you keep any intermediate arrays.

You can't use `array_filter()`, because it only receives the values, not the keys. So do it in your `foreach` loop.

```
function array_filter_recursive($input)
{
    foreach ($input as $key => &$value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $value = array_filter_recursive($value);
            if (empty($value)) {
                unset($input[$key]);
            }
        } elseif ($key != 'access') {
            unset($input[$key]);
        }
    }
    return $input;
}
```

Comment: "You can't use array_filter(), because it only receives the values, not the keys." ...are you sure?

Comment: I always forget that there's an optional `$mode` argument.

Answer (score 0):

The solution can be a little leaner than Barmar's answer.

As you iterate, if you encounter an subarray, recursively traverse. Otherwise, when you encounter a non-array and its key is not `access`, then prune it.

My snippet will use the magic `__FUNCTION__` to avoid the bloat of repeating the verbose yet indicative function name.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/mYLHT))

```
function removeIfNotArrayAndNotSiblingOfAccess($array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => &$value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $value = (__FUNCTION__)($value);
        } elseif ($key != 'access') {
            unset($array[$key]);
        }
    }
    return $array;
}

var_export(removeIfNotArrayAndNotSiblingOfAccess($array));
```